# Memory use increase when scrolling ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm currently trying to create an ItemsControl (ListView) to scroll a list of strings (as a demo for a more complicated scenario). In doing so, I've noticed that when initially scrolling the list the memory usage of my application increases significantly.

Here is the code I am using for the XAML and the code-behind:

```
<ListView VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="1" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" x:Name="rowsList" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Item" VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border>
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>
</ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            list.Add("testStringtestStringtestStringtestStringtestStringtestStringtestString");
        }

        rowsList.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

This is the memory profile from VS diagnostics tools:
[Memory profile whilst scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9vcm.png)

The memory usage is stable but when I start scrolling the list the memory use spikes up significantly. When scrolling back up the list, however, the memory usage doesn't seem to increase. I've tried a lot of ways to get round this but can't seem to rectify this simple issue.

Can anybody shed some light on this for me?
Thanks.

Comment: Given that the `ListView` is virtualizing (not creating views for all 10,000 strings at once), is it surprising that as you scroll down (and creates the views) the memory increases? What is your expectation?

Comment: I believed that virtualization meant that as you scroll and items pop into view, they are dynamically created, but then as they pop out of view they are destroyed, and that this should result in a fairly steady use of memory. Is this now how the UI virtualization works?

Comment: You're right, but I thought there would be a lag in the view disappearing and it being destroyed by the GC. However, I noticed that you have the virtualization set as recycling, so the views are not being destroyed. Anyway, I don't know the answer to your question, but I did notice that increasing the list size to 100,000 or even 1,000,000 doesn't increase the memory by that much. The extra memory could be some internal overhead by the rendering system.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe you here. Although, if it is some issue with the rendering system, there's not much hope for me fixing this issue, which is a shame.